# call function from useEffect and other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

i have a child component which emits an action to the parent component with a event:

**Child component:**

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState([0, 5]);

  const handleChange = (_, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    props.updateData(newValue)
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <GrandSonComponent
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Parent component:**

```
export const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const { appData, appDispatch } = React.useContext(Context);

  function fetchElements(val) {
    fetchData(val);
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  useEffect(() => { return fetchData() }, []);

  async function fetchData(params) {
    const res = await axios.get('/url', { params });
    appDispatch({ type: "LOAD_ELEMENTS", elements: res.data });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent updateData={fetchElements}  />
    <div>
     .
     .
     .
   )
};
```

i would like to know how to remove this line `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

I need to add this line, because otherwise i see the eslint error:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchData'. Either include it or remove the 
dependency array.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

i need to use `fetchData(params)` function for the first time page is rendered and when user change/click value of child component with no eslit warnings!

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question, but `useEffect(() => { return fetchData() }, []);` is not how you would call the function the first time it renders. When you return from a use effect, it will assume it's a cleanup function, in this case to run on **unmount**. `fetchData`also returns a promise, so it would break when it tries to call it. Remove the`return` keyword.

Comment: Same result, does not fix the issue!

Comment: *This doesn't answer your specific question* - it wasn't supposed to. It was pointing out a second problem in your code.

Comment: You can use `useRef` for the same. [stackoverflow.com/a/70255826/8494462](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70255826/8494462)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to return the result of calling `fetchData()` function inside the `useEffect` hook.

Now coming to your problem, reason why you get a warning is because missing the dependencies of the `useEffect` could lead to bugs due to closures. React recommends that you don't omit any dependencies of the `useEffect` hook, `useCallback` hook, etc.

This sometimes leads to infinite loop of state update and re-render but that can be prevented by either using `useCallback` hook or other ways that could prevent `useEffect` hook from executing after each re-render of the component.

In your case, you could fix the problem by following the steps mentioned below:

1. Wrapping `fetchData` function in a `useCallback` hook

   ```
   const fetchData = useCallback(async (params) => {
      const res = await axios.get('/url', { params });
      appDispatch({ type: "LOAD_ELEMENTS", elements: res.data });
   }, []);
   ```
2. Add `fetchData` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       fetchData();
   }, [fetchData]);
   ```

Comment: thanks, if i add `useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, [fetchData])` warning appear in fetchData function; `The 'fetchData' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 26) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the definition of 'fetchData' in its own useCallback()`

Comment: See step 1 in the answer.