# How do I run a seperate function inside of useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing a multi filter component, which can filter by keyword, category work types and so on...
so this is one useEffect Hook, this filters by entering keyword of job titles and job category.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const newFilteredJobs = jobs.filter((job) => {
      return (
        job.title.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchField) &&
        job.category
          .toString()
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .includes(categorySearchField)
      );
    });
    setFilteredJobs(newFilteredJobs);
  }, [jobs, searchField, categorySearchField]);
```

I would like to filter one more which is work type, however, this requires pass props from child component to parent component.

This is in the parent component

```
<WorkType jobs={jobs} onFilterJobsByType={filterJobsByTypeHandler} />
```

This is my `filterJobsByTypeHandler` function

```
  const filterJobsByTypeHandler = (jobTypes) => {
    console.log(`selected job types are ${jobTypes}`);
    const newFilteredJobs = jobs.filter((job) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < jobTypes.length; i++) {
        if (job.jobType !== undefined) {
          return job.jobType.toString() === jobTypes[i];
        }
      }
    });
    setFilteredJobs(newFilteredJobs);
  };
```

I need to select and deselect job types to refresh the filtered jobs, I suppose I need to use useEffect hook? As I can control the dependencies. But i am struggling how I can put the function inside of the useEffect hook.

I tried to use useCallBack Hook, but I could not get the full list of jobs by deselecting the selected work types.

Comment: does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410369/can-i-call-separate-function-in-useeffect

Comment: @Georgemff I looked up this answer, but not really.

Comment: Hi, @AlexZhang, Do you have something like `CodeSandbox`?

Comment: hi @BikasLin i dont, but you can find my code on github https://github.com/karmalexz/owcareer-backend and https://github.com/karmalexz/owcarwylee-career thank you.

Comment: @AlexZhang, so what is your issue exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stored selected `jobTypes` as `state` in the `Search.jsx`.

```
const [jobTypes, setJobTypes] = useState([]);
```

And set the `jobTypes` from the `WorkType.jsx` by modifying `filterJobsByTypeHandler`.

```
const filterJobsByTypeHandler = (_jobTypes) => {
 setJobTypes(_jobTypes)
};
```

Finally, I added the `jobTypes` as a `dependency array` of the `useEffect` to filter the jobs.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newFilteredJobs = jobs.filter((job) => {
    //   console.log(job.country.toString() === selectedCountries.toString());
    let filtered = job.title.toString().toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchField) &&
      job.category
        .toString()
        .toLocaleLowerCase()
        .includes(categorySearchField)
        //    &&
        // job.country.toString() === selectedCountries.toString()
    if (jobTypes.length) {
      filtered  = filtered && jobTypes.includes(job?.jobType?.[0] || "")
    }
    return filtered;
  });
  setFilteredJobs(newFilteredJobs);
}, [jobs, searchField, categorySearchField, jobTypes]);
```

Here is the [`CodeSandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/sheriff-rango/owcarwylee-career/draft/condescending-microservice?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522claqnn3mu0013l3i7d5hd5lg8%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522claqnnrov009i356pot1xiz96%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D) which contains full code.
Hope this would solve your issue.